# Where to store request specific values in Spring MVC?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I'm using Spring MVC and I want to store request specific values somewhere so that they can be fetched throughout my request context.  Say I want to set a value into the context in my Controller (or some sort of handler) and then fetch that value from some other part of the Spring request/response cycle (could be a view, view resolver, interceptor, exception handler, etc)... how would I do that?

My question is:

Does Spring MVC already provide a method to do what I described above?
If Spring doesn't have this functionality, any ideas on the best way to do this (by extending something maybe)?

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you need to pass an object from your controller to view, you can use Spring's ModelMap.

```
@RequestMapping("/list")
    public String list(ModelMap modelMap) {
            // ... do foo

             modelMap.addAttribute("greeting", "hello");

        return viewName;
    }
```

on your view:

```
   <h1>${greeting}</h1>
```

Comment: Thanks for the feedback... I didn't word my question very well.  Setting values in the model works great, but what can I do if I wanted to fetch these values from some other part of the Spring workflow?

Answer (score 1):

You could use sessionAttributes.

[Session Attributes](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.0.M1/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-ann-sessionattrib)

I took the latest version of the api (3.1) since you didn't mention your version of spring.

Comment: I misunderstood what you were asking.  If you want to have those values available for other requests then use sessionAttributes.